how long can I keep my residency in Italy after starting to work in Germany? Do I need to register my residency in Germany immediately?
I need to know about keeping my permannet residency in Italy, while I am planing to work in Germany. I am entitled as a long EU resident (Permanent Resident UE lungo periodo which is unlimited permission to stay and work in Italy) which I acquired from Italy.
I have filled the application for Italian citizenship in December 2022. I have to keep my residence (as tax residency) in Italy until I receive the citizenship application response, otherwise I risk loosing the right to acquire Italian citizenship. I want to know is there any solution to start working in Germany without applying for a residence in Germany? I know if I want to work for a company in Germany based on a work contract, I should register my residency there to be able to opening a back account and this will automatically revoke my residency in Italy.


I have filled the application for Italian citizenship in December 2022. I have to keep my residence (as tax residency) in Italy until I receive the citizenship application response, otherwise I risk loosing the right to acquire Italian citizenship.

Thinking of it as “keeping your tax residence” doesn't sound right. The requirement is presumably to actually live in the country. I don't know the details for Italy but usually it's also required to intend to stay in the country so leaving immediately after receiving citizenship might create problems.
In other words, if you reside elsewhere, you risk loosing the right to acquire Italian citizenship irrespective of the local registration requirements.

I want to know is there any solution to start working in Germany without applying for a residence in Germany?

No. In fact, even if you don't work, it's required to register within two weeks of moving to a new address.

I know if I want to work for a company in Germany based on a work contract, I should register my residency there to be able to opening a back account and this will automatically revoke my residency in Italy.

Why would that automatically revoke your residency in Italy? Legally speaking, those two are not necessarily linked and practically speaking I am pretty sure there is no routine data exchange between the two countries. The fact that you would actually be living and working in Germany is a larger issue than the registration requirement.

Since 2015 it is a Federal law and the period is 2 weeks. §17 - Registration, deregistration - Federal Act on Registration (1) Anyone who moves into a residence shall register with the registration authorities within two weeks of moving in.

@MarkJohnson Fixed, thanks!
